# Text floating around CSS-div positioned in

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have a large div with a small div inside it.
I want the smaller div to be positioned at the bottom of the large div.
So I have positioned the small div using "bottom: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute;"
The large div has "position: relative;"
The small div appears where it should but the text does not float around it.
I have tried "float: left;" in combinations with various alternatives of display, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I don't think it will help anyone. Please look at this image instead. It shows what I want to achieve. I want the inner div to be positioned at the bottom of the outer div, no matter how long the text is or how many paragraphs I have. And the text should float around it: http://www.sirugo.net/divfloat.png

Answer (score 0):

Float will only work with relative position.
When you set one element to Absolute, it does not count as a space taken in the element.

Also, to make the float works you need to put set float into the element next to it.

Comment: So it's not possible to place a div at the bottom of a containing div so that the text inside the containing div flows around it? 

See: http://www.sirugo.net/divfloat.png

Comment: Far as I know it is not posssible. Usualy you will need to use Img to do something like that. In my case I tried to find a way but it look there is a glitch. The only possible will be that you use IMG tag and make a P tag next to it to have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Didn't work

Make a wrapper for your smaller div ( a div in between the two in your example), and set it with absolute positioning with bottom and left as zero width 100%.

Then make your smaller div pos:relative and float that div left and clear left.

I believe that should work.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but it did not work. Not sure I understood exactly what you meant though. Please take a look at the source code in my example: http://sirugo.net/divindiv.html

Comment: @sirugo I will have a peek tomorrow afternoon.  If I can sit down and look I'm sure it will go quickly...

Comment: Will be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: @sirugo Sorry, it looks like I was wrong.  The content just went behind the div as before.  There have been similar questions on SO, and it looks like the best solution uses javascript, which is not my specialty.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I'll have to drop it then. I'll use some other similar layout.

Comment: @sirugo I suppose you COULD put it at top right and use CSS transformation to rotate the outer div 180 degrees, then also rotate your text 180 degrees....  that is about my last shot for a CSS only solution.  It depends on how much you care about older browsers.

Comment: Thanks but that seems a bit too desperate. I'll be using a different layout :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS position (absolute/fixed/relative) brings the element to upper layer, leaving the source order dependency layer.

Positioned elements never care about the display paint order of other elements. I don't see a way to make positioned and non-positioned element react together and to care for their painting behavior.

If you need solution like your [[image]](http://www.sirugo.net/divfloat.png), you can use float but content inserted with texts. Like:

```
div {
    font: 14px Arial;
    width:400px;
    margin:30px auto;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:justify;

}

img {
    margin:10px 20px 0 0;
    float:left;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KY8FG/